# jQuery: How can I check if a function exists in an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing

I have the following code and need to check if a value exists as an array key.

I can't seem to generate the `index` of the key even though it does exist, any help would be great.

Code:

```
var run = { // store the actions to trigger

    block : function() {
        console.log('Blocking…');
    },

    warning : function() {
        console.log('Warning…');
    }

};

console.log( $.inArray( 'warning' , run ) );
```

As far as I can see, `warning` exists inside `run{}` and should return an `index` of `1`.

Why isn't the above doesn't get found (`index` is returned as `-1`).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: `$.inArray()` expects the 2nd parameter to be an actual array. Something like `var arr = [1,2,'three', 3.5,4];`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`run` isn't an array (it's just a plain object) so it doesn't have an index. Even though `block` comes before `warning`, objects are order-less, so you can't say that `run` has an index of 1.

To check if an object has a particular key, simply check:

```
if ('warning' in run) {...}
```

Or:

```
if (run.warning) {...}
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks for your help, that makes perfect sense. I should really know by now that `{} != []`. Either way, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
console.log(run.warning);
```

If you get a value, you've found your function.

As for the index - `run` isn't an array, it is an object (or a hash, or a map, depending on when you're coming from). Objects' properties do not have orders, and they are not even guaranteed to keep the same order every time you iterate over them.